# Update room field on last day of month

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-room

I want to update a specific field of a database at the end of every month. I tried looking into AlarmManager and PendingIntent yet I can't seem to wrap my head around it as most questions focus on an alarm going off daily here on stackoverflow. Please help.

Edit: I discovered that PendingIntent is not the right thing to attempt to use in this case as I am using a feature within the application. So how do I write an AlarmManager with an Intent, keeping the last day of the month in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update sqlite database field, This is the code to get Current Day of Month, compare last update day of database with current day , you will get desired result

```
   public static String getCurrentDayMonth()
{
      String csCurrentDate  = "";

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 ;
    int mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

    String csDay = mDay < 10? "0" + String.valueOf(mDay) : String.valueOf(mDay);
    String csMonth = mMonth < 10? "0" + String.valueOf(mMonth) : String.valueOf(mMonth);

    csCurrentDate = csDay + "/" + csMonth + "/" + String.valueOf(mYear);

    return csCurrentDate;
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean but it isn't exactly what I need. I want to use the Dao's update feature on the last day of the month to change a field in my room database.